# How to show loading until next item or an error arrives with observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Now I try to use `observables`. The user will may log off and log on as another user, so perfect for a stream. But how and where to I implement my `this.loadingService.showLoading();` and `this.loadingService.hideLoading();`

It cannot be in the `subscription`, since this never completes. And `this.loginService.login(credentials)` also gives back a `user$`-stream

```
public user$: Observable<any> = this.loginService.user$;

this.subscription.add(this.user$.subscribe(value => {
    this.user = value;
}, err => {
    console.error('error in user stream', err);
}, () => {
    console.error('impossible')
}));

userLoginHandle(credentials) {
    this.loginService.login(credentials)
}
```

Comment: I dint quite understand your question why not just simply : `this.loadingService.showLoading(); 
 this.subscription.add(this.user$.subscribe(value => {
    this.user = value; this.loadingService.hideLoading();
}, err => {
    console.error('error in user stream', err); this.loadingService.hideLoading();
}, () => {
    console.error('impossible')
}));`

Comment: What if there arrives a user without `loginService.login()` did get called, then `hideLoading()` would not be possible since `showLoading()` did never get called.

Comment: a user can arrive not threw login?

Comment: @YonatanLilling yes, on app boot, through saved state, because the user may not want's to login on every start of the app. With Promise I would just do `LoginService.login.then().catch()` but with observables I'm struggling to find out how's the right way, to implement stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
this.subscription.add(this.user$.subscribe(value => {
    this.loggingIn = false;
    this.user = value;
}, err => {
    this.loggingIn = false;
    console.error('error in user stream', err);
}, () => {
    console.error('impossible')
}));

userLoginHandle(credentials) {
    this.loggingIn = true;
    this.loginService.login(credentials)
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a working solution, but using a promise instead, feels so much cleaner and is less code. Of course there are way's to get it done, but what i really wanted, is a clean solution. but nevermind for the moment I decided to not use anywhere `observables` only on places where i think it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement a setter to the user object

```
set user(value) { 
  if(value) {
    this.loadingService.hideLoading();
  }
}
```